# Получение выделенного индекса/экземпляра класса строки в DataGrid WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Добрый день.

Каким образом можно получить индекс строки или экземпляр класса выбранной в DataGrid если в него передается свойство `ObservableCollection<Layer>` ?
Хотелось бы реализовать удаление строки через кнопу, но не знаю как реализовать получение индекса/экземпляра класса для удаления его из `ObservableCollection<Layer>`, желательно получить бы экземпляр класса так как необходимо еще перед удалением в классе передать это имя в другой метод.

Краткий исходный код

Model

```
public class Layer
    {
        private string _nameLayer;
        /// <summary>
        /// свойство Имени слоя
        /// </summary>
        public string NameLayer
        {
            get { return _nameLayer; }
            set { _nameLayer = value; }                
        }

        private bool _showLayer;
        public bool ShowLayer
        {
            get { return _showLayer; }
            set { _showLayer = value; }
        }
    }
```

MainViewModel

```
 public class MainViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region PropertyChangedEventHandler
        /// <summary>
        /// Метод проверяющий изменилось ли свойство
        /// </summary>
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        #endregion

public MainViewModel()
        {
            LayerProperties layerProperties = new LayerProperties();
            _layersCollection = layerProperties.ReadLayer();        

        ClickCommandAddLayer = new Command(arg=>{
            _layersCollection.Add(layerProperties.AddLayer());
        });
        ClickCommandDeleterLayer=new Command(arg =>
        {
            //_layersCollection.Remove(layerProperties.DeleteLayer());
        });
    }



    private ObservableCollection<Layer> _layersCollection;
    public ObservableCollection<Layer> LayersCollection
    {
        get { return _layersCollection; }
        set { _layersCollection = value; }
    }

    public ICommand ClickCommandAddLayer { get; set; }
    public ICommand ClickCommandDeleterLayer { get; set; }

}
```

View

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <mainViewModel:MainViewModel x:Key="Vm" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Vm}}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--  Добавляем разметку для кнопок  -->
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Button
            Name="AddLayer"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Command="{Binding ClickCommandAddLayer}"
            Cursor="Hand"
            ToolTip="Создать новый слой">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="../../Source_Icons/PropertiesLayers/Create.png" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>

        <Button
            Name="DeleterLayer"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Command="{Binding ClickCommandDeleterLayer}"
            ToolTip="Удалить слой">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="../../Source_Icons/PropertiesLayers/Deliter.png" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
    <!--  Отображение в Таблице свойста слоев  -->
    <DataGrid
        Name="Layers"
        Grid.Row="1"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        CanUserAddRows="False"
        CanUserDeleteRows="False"
        CanUserResizeRows="False"
        HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#FFE4DDDD"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=LayersCollection, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        VerticalGridLinesBrush="#00000000">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn
                Width="*"
                Binding="{Binding NameLayer}"
                Header="Название слоя" />
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn
                Width="auto"
                Binding="{Binding ShowLayer}"
                Header="Выкл" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте свойство `SelectedLayer` типа `Layer`:

```
private Layer selectedLayer;
public Layer SelectedLayer
{
   get { return selectedLayer; }
   set { selectedLayer = value; OnPropertyChanged("SelectedLayer"); }
}
```

Удалять так:

```
layersCollection.Remove(selectedLayer);
```

в xaml:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding LayersCollection}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLayer}"/>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Чет сам не додумался.

Comment: @KJfe, Пожалуйста. Рад помочь!

Answer (score -1):

XAML

```
<DataGrid Name="MainDataGrid" />
<Button Click="DeleteItem" Grid.Row="1">Delete Row</Button>
```

Codebegind

```
private ObservableCollection<Node> collection = new ObservableCollection<Node> { new Node(), new Node() };

private void DeleteItem(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (MainDataGrid.SelectedItem is Node node
        && MessageBox.Show($"Delete Row {node.Name} ?", "", MessageBoxButton.YesNo) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
    {
        collection.Remove(node);
    }
}
```

Класс

```
public class Node
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "Default Name";
}
```

Comment: За что дизлайк? Объект, выделенный в датагрид, получен и удалён через кнопку, как просил автор